# Error with connecting mysql database using java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

when i am triying to connect my sql database using java... it gives an error with creating driver.

String driverName = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
    Class.forName(driverName);

it dosen't allow to create this driver. is this stancard coding "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver", how do we use this codin and what is the use of this coding?? thank you!

Comment: what is the error you are getting??

Comment: i am getting driver not found error..

Comment: please have the mysql-connector.jar in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

`org.gjt.mm.msyql.Driver` is an old class name kept around for backwards compatibility. Use `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` instead. [See this MySQL reference for usage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check if you are having the `mysql-connector-java.jar` in your classpath, if not please get it from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.22) and put it in the classpath

The old classname `org.gjt.mm.msyql.Driver` is kept for backwards compatibility reasons, if you can, you should update it to `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`